# Cannot relay text with \\ in it with Python

Tags: python-3.x, text

I am receiving a ping when connecting to irc.freenode.net and the contents is something like:
`ping :1[VA\[sd}` so the backslash gets escaped with a second backslash and creates a invalid ping reply.

I printed the PING and I see `PING :1[VA\\[sd}` so I am escaping the backslashes somewhere with a third or even a fourth backslash. This makes sense since I did not want people to send `/ctcp bauderr ping\nquit i can make no sense` and force my client to quit. But I noticed after I removed that PING translating code, everything just works fine and when I print to a text file I see only 1 backslash now that it is fixed, whereas before I would probably see 2 backslashes with actually having 3 or 4 backslashes. All I now is that I was sending an invalid PING reply to sign-on the server with, and when I removed the code that was translating to microsecond timing it just started working. Later on that day irc.freenode.net changed their PING to *.freenode.net which does not require any escaping so I have nothing left to test with. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: You likely need to double up the backslashes.  It's because a backslash is the escape character in Python (and a lot of other languages), so, e.g., `\n` is a new line.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings describes what's going on

Comment: We need more context, perhaps a snippet of code where you have the problem. But python does not add backslashes. Its just that python uses the backslash as an escape for non printable characters. But that's only for human visible displays. In fact, not all backslashes are escapes. You can check with a list: `print(list("ping :1[VA\[sd}"))` --> `['p', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', ':', '1', '[', 'V', 'A', '\\', '[', 's', 'd', '}']`. Notice that double backslash in the list is really just the single backslash character with human display. Print your troublesome string as a list and see what you get.